# NameError in Users#show - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am following Michael Hurtl's Rails Tutorial and In Chapter 11 When i want to view the profile page of the User i get this error :

NameError in Users#show undefined local variable or method `micropost' and This line of Code is highlighted in red :

**<%= link_to micropost.user.name , micropost.user%>**

Here's My code:

**microposts_controller.rb**

```
class MicropostsController < ApplicationController
        before_action :authenticate_user! , only: [:create,:destroy]

    def create
        @micropost = current_user.microposts.build(micropost_params)

        if @micropost.save
            flash[:success] = "Micropost created"
            redirect_to root_url
        else
            render 'pages/home'
        end
    end

    def destroy
    end

    private

    def micropost_params
        params.require(:micropost).permit(:content)
    end
end
```

**users_controller.rb**

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
    before_action :authenticate_user! , only: [:edit,:update,:destroy]

    def index
        @users = User.all
    end

    def show
        @user = User.find(params[:id])
        @microposts = @user.microposts
    end

end
```

**microposts/_microposts.html.erb**

```
<%= link_to micropost.user.name , micropost.user%>
```

**views/users/show.html.erb**

```
  <h2>User Profile</h2>
    <% if @user.microposts.any? %>
    <h3>Microposts</h3>
    <%= @user.microposts.count%>
    <%= render 'microposts/microposts' %>
    <%end%>
```

Comment: you didn't set `micropost` variable to partial, add to your question, how you add partial into view

Answer (score 0):

it seems you didn't set `micropost` variable to partial

you can fix it in next way:

```
<%= render partial: 'microposts/_microposts', collection: @microposts %>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should have something like this in your partial:

```
<% @microposts.each do |micropost| %>
<%= link_to micropost.user.name , micropost.user%>
<% end %>
```